# "." not being parsed as part of a require() Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on a project and ran into an issue when I was reorganizing my files. The "." on my requires are not being parsed.

When I run my program I get a

> Error: Cannot find module './src/map/createMap.js'

Here is my code:

server.js (main file):

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
//Completely unrelated code...
const gameConsole = require('./src/backend/console.js');
gameConsole.start();
```

console.js:

```
const {createMap} = require('./src/map/createMap.js'); << Error thrown here
const Server = require('./server.js').Server; << Error thrown here if I use path.resolve()
```

I've tried using path.resolve(), and that works fine. When I log process.cwd() it has the path of my root directory (the one with server.js). I am considering storing the paths as global variables. Thanks for your help.

EDITS:

Sample of file structure:

```
(root)
|_server.js
|_src
   |_backend
   | |_console.js
   |_map
     |_createMap.js
```

Here is createMap.js, on my git repo: https://github.com/ArkinSolomon/zombie-fight/blob/master/src/map/createMap.js

Comment: could you show your `'./src/map/createMap.js'` code, and double check the paths

Comment: It might help to diagram just enough of your new file/directory structure to explain where server.js is relative to console.js.

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar Edited my question

Comment: @stealththeninja edited my question

Comment: @ArkinSolomon, it's better practice to paste relevant code than linking to somewhere else. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've linked, the path to `./src/map/createMap.js` in `console.js` is wrong.

The correct path would be

```
../map/createMap.js
```

Go up 1 folder `../` then you've access to `map` folder

And for server in `console.js`, the path would be:

```
const { Server } = require('../../server.js')
```

Go up 2 folder `../../` as `console.js` is 2 folders deep relative to `server.js`

Comment: So do I **have** to use `..` as oppose to `.`, because that's what I thought the purpose of `process.cwd()` was?

Comment: in `*nix` environment `..` is 1 dir up and `.` is same `dir`. About `process.cwd()` it's equivalent `pwd` in *nix

Comment: I thought `process.cwd()` was set by `process.chdir()`, and that `process.cwd()` is the same as `.`

Comment: From docs `The process.chdir() method changes the current working directory of the Node.js process` so that would be equivalent to `cd` in *nix, which I doubt would be helpful when you're giving path to `require` as require is wrapped in function befure execution and node passes the current path as __dirname

Comment: @Arkin: `require` resolves relative paths relative to source file, not to the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use "../map/createMap.js"?

Comment: Please add some more description about the answer. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer